# Fixed the jump height consistency but result losing height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, rigid-bodies

I am working on my character jump base on `Rigidbody.velocity`.

here is my jump:

```
    [SerializeField] private float jumpPickHeight;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpPickTime;
    private float _jumpInitVelocith;
    private float _gravity;
    void OnEnable()
    {
        //jumped height
        _start_Y = _md.transform.position.y;
        CalculateInitVelocithAndGravity();

        _currentSpeed_Y = _jumpInitVelocith;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        //jumped height
        _jumpedHeight = _md.transform.position.y - _start_Y;

        _currentSpeed_Y = Mathf.Max(_currentSpeed_Y - _gravity * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        _rb.velocity += _currentSpeed_Y * Vector3.up;
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        _currentSpeed_Y = 0;
        _start_Y = 0;

        //jumped height
        Debug.Log(_jumpedHeight);
        _jumpedHeight = 0;
    }
```

and here is my calculation of jump data

```
    public void CalculateInitVelocithAndGravity()
    {
        if (jumpPickHeight <= 0 || jumpPickTime <= 0)
            return;

        _jumpInitVelocith = (2 * JumpPickHeight) / jumpPickTime;
        _gravity = (2 * JumpPickHeight) / (jumpPickTime * jumpPickTime);
    }
```

At first, i use `Update()` but causing jump height being not consist, `_jumpedHeight` result at around 1.8 - 2.1 when i set `_jumpPickHeight` to 2.

i fixed the consistency by just changing `Update()` to `FixedUpdate()`, but always result 1.8xxxxx. Since i saw the relation of

`jumpPickHeight` and `jumpedHeight` is linear,

`1` result (lets say)`0.92`

`2` result (lets say)`1.84`

so on, i cheese it by multiplying a error factor to minimize the amount of error (like let say 1.000023 for 1 and 2.000046 for 2)

```
    public const float JUMP_PICK_HEIGHT_ERROR = 1.0927f;
    public float JumpPickHeight { get => _jumpPickHeight * JUMP_PICK_HEIGHT_ERROR; }
    [SerializeField] float _jumpPickHeight;
```

but still not exactly equal the `_jumpPickHeight` i want.

tho I got it kind of working, i want to know what piece am I missing. how can I get rid of the error factor?

Comment: I think you are missing to take gravity into account for your jump height ... or where exactly does the `jumpPickTime` come from? .. usually you would calculate it somewhat like e.g. `velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(2 * Mathf.Abs(gravity) * _jumpPickHeight);`

Comment: I set _jumpPickHeight and _jumpPickTime i want in inspector, and calculate the _initVelocith and gravity in `CalculateInitVelocithAndGravity()` before enable this component

Comment: but is this actually the gravity assigned in the Unity physics settings? You should afaik not calculate the gravity but rather take the existing gravity into account for calculating everything else

Comment: I didn't touch `Physics.gravity` at all. All i've done is basically just call `**_rb.velocity** = V3(0,_initVelocith,0)` at the first frame, then minus the amount(`_gravity * Time.deltaTime`) until 0.

Comment: And sorry, the initV and garv in CalculateInitVelocithAndGravity() are passed in to _currentSpeed_Y and _gravity onEnable

Comment: And i don't have use gravity on in the rb :)